# Code builds on Visual Studio but the test has errors on NUnit

Tags: .net, selenium, c#-4.0, nunit

My code builds successfully on Visual Studio 13 premium. However, when I test it on Nunit, it doesn't show that it failed but it shows that there is an error. I am new to NUnit and unit testing and would appreciate any help that comes on the way.

Here is the Error that I got:

```
at Automation.AL.Tests.DataTestMethod.RunTestMethod() in c:\QA\testautomation\AL\AL\Tests\DataSourceAttribute.cs:line 69
at NUnit.Core.TestMethod.RunTestCase(TestResult testResult)
--NoSuchElementException
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
at OpenQA.Selenium.By.FindElement(ISearchContext context)
at   Automation.AL.Framework.UI.Pages.Administration.AdminPage.ClickTab[T]() in c:\QA\testautomation\AL\AL\Framework\UI\Pages\Administration\AdminPage.cs:line 43
at Automation.AL.Tests.Fixtures.Test.TestCase(String user, String password, String agentName, String destinationFolder, String fileName1, String fsDestinationFldr, String fsFileType, String metaElement1, String metaElement2, String metaElement3, XmlElement data) in c:\QA\testautomation\AL\AL\Tests\Fixtures\Test.cs:line 91
```

However, the error is on line 91 and this is how it looks like:

```
            var libraryPage = skillsSettingsPage.Open<AjaxLibraryPage>();
```

Please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: "Sorry, I cannot post anything because of my comapny policies" Well you should be able to create a short but complete example which *doesn't* contain any confidential code, but displays the same behaviour. Then you can post the code and the error. Without knowing what the error is, it's very hard to help you.

Comment: Ok I will do that and post it. Thank you for not downvoting

Comment: @JonSkeet I edited it

Comment: So it looks like your test tries to find an element that doesn't exist, within the `ClickTab` method (line 43). Either the test needs changing, or you need to make sure that element *does* exist...

Comment: that is line 43 AdminPage.cs?

Comment: Yes, as per the stack trace...

Comment: Right. I was more interested in the Line 91 test.cs error

Comment: Um, that line is calling (possibly indirectly) line 43, which is then causing the issue. That's why they're both in the same stack trace. If you're new at reading stack traces, it might be best to get a colleague to help explain them to you.

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense. I will look into it. Thanks Jon!